# Acceso a ModBus deja de funcionar al insertarlo en código Flask

Tags: python, flask

Tengo un código en python que se comunica con un PLC; ejecutado individualmente, **funciona perfectamente**:

```
import modbus_tk
import modbus_tk.defines as cst
from modbus_tk import modbus_tcp

def main():
    device_id = 255
    master = modbus_tcp.TcpMaster("192.168.1.2")
    master.set_timeout(3)   
    master.set_verbose(True)  
    data = master.execute(device_id, cst.READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, 100, 43) 
    print ("data    ", data)
    print ("data[0] ", data[0])

while True:
    main()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Ahora, estoy intentando combinarlo con `Flask` para realizar un sistema *puente*, que reciba/envíe al PLC basándome en un formulario `HTML`.

```
codigo python:
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import time
import modbus_tk
import modbus_tk.defines as cst
from modbus_tk import modbus_tcp

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def inicio():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/procesar', methods=['POST'])
def procesar():
    nombre = request.form.get("nombre")
    edad = request.form.get("edad")
    lote = request.form.get("lote")
    escalamax = request.form.get("escalamax")
    escalamin = request.form.get("escalamin")
    entrada = request.form.get("entrada")
    print(entrada)
    return render_template("mostrar.html", nombre=nombre, edad=edad, lote=lote, escalamax=escalamax, escalamin=escalamin, entrada=entrada, data=data)

def main():
    device_id = 255
    master = modbus_tcp.TcpMaster("192.168.1.2")
    master.set_timeout(3)   
    master.set_verbose(True)  
    data = master.execute(device_id, cst.READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, 100, 43) 
    print ("data    ", data)
    print ("data[0] ", data[0])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=True)

while True:
    main()
    time.sleep(1)



  codigo HTML:
  <form method="POST" action="{{url_for('procesar')}}">
        <input name="nombre" required type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
        <br><br>
        <input name="edad" required type="number" placeholder="Edad">
        <br><br>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lote">LOTE</label>
       <input type="text" name="lote" id="lote" class="form-control" required placeholder="INGRESE EL LOTE"  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('porfavor ingrese el lote')"  oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" step="1" min= />
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="escala_max">ESCALA MAX</label>
        <input type="number" name="escalamax" id="escala_max" class="form-control" required placeholder="INGRESE ESCALA MAX"  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('porfavor ingrese la escala maxima')"  oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" step="1" />
         </div>
         <br><br>
         <div class="form-group">
    <label for="escala_min">ESCALA MIN</label>
    <input type="number" name="escalamin" id="escala_min" class="form-control" required placeholder="INGRESE ESCALA MIN"  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('porfavor ingrese la escala minima')"  oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"/>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tipo_de_entrada">ENTRADA :</label>
        <input type="radio" id="volt" name="entrada" value="voltaje" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(' porfavor ingrese el tipo de entrada')"  onclick="clearValidity();" required/> VOLTAJE
       <input type="radio" name="entrada" value="4-20" id="corr1" onclick="clearValidity()" /> CORRIENTE(4-20 mA)
     <input type="radio" name="entrada" value="020" id="corr2" onclick="clearValidity()" /> CORRIENTE(0-20 mA)
       </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
```

Sin embargo, ahora **la parte de comunicación con `modbus` deja de funcionar**, mientras que la parte `Flask` **si lo hace**.

- ¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Como lo soluciono ?

Comment: Si tienes el formulario HTML, este se despliega por en navegador a la pantalla del usuario, cuando el usuario llena los datos del formulario; debes capturarlos con javascript y enviarlos al lado del servidor; no veo como haces este ultimo punto de enviar los datos; puedes ser mas especifico?

Comment: listo ya modifique la publicacion agrege un fragmento de mi HTML en donde envio los datos a python,gracias por la ayuda

Comment: listo, según veo en `procesar` recibes los datos; debes imprimir que estas recibiendo por `POST` o `GET`  con eso verifica si recibes datos.

Comment: esa parte funciona bien,de hecho muestro los datos del formulario en otro HTML llamado mostrar.html,pero lo extraño es que la parte con la que hago la comunicacion deja de funcionar

Comment: estas seguro que esta es la ip para conectarte a dispositivo PLC: `master = modbus_tcp.TcpMaster("192.168.1.2")` incrementa el timeout a 60 para ver si funciona con mas tiempo.

Comment: si de hecho ya he podido comunicarme con otros PLC´s en el pasado con ese codigo y funciona bien,aqui el problema radica en que cuando  junto el codigo de la comunicacion con flask la parte de comunicacion  no funciona,incluso si desconecto el PLC ,no recibo errores

Comment: pero entonces tiene que hacer la verificación sobre la conexión si existe.

Comment: ya hice la prueba haciendo un ping a la ip del PLC y si me responde,pero en python no tengo ninguna respuesta,es como si nos se ejecutara la funcion

Comment: hermano trata de hacer el test dentro de pyton no con un ping desde otra aplicacion/terminal; cuando compruebas conectividad debes hacerlo desde el software emisor

Comment: ya probe ejecutando el codigo de comunicacion(sin flask) y funciona,puedo leer los datos,pero al juntalos nada

Comment: verifica esto: http://dixu.me/2015/10/26/How_to_Allow_Remote_Connections_to_Flask_Web_Service/

Comment: @LuisLIRE Vista la conversación en los comentarios, he editado también el título.